# How to edit sitemap.xml generated by Yoast

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, sitemap, yoast

I've been looking for the location of the sitemap.xml that generated by Yoast because I've got the white space issue thing like this: https://kb.yoast.com/kb/xml-sitemap-error/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of updating the existing file I copied the [**page source**](https://www.wikihow.com/View-Source-Code) of the xml and apply the fix to a new one and use the .htaccess to reflect the content with the same URL

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^broken-sitemap.xml$ /good-sitemap.xml [L]
```

> broken-sitemap.xml

is the path of the broken xml
and

> good-sitemap.xml

is the fix one